# Catel - Use ModelBase as "Data Transfer Object" in Service-Based Application

Tags: catel

I am currently creating some examples with Catel.

The Scenario I have in mind:

- Database Server
- WebServer with WCF DataService
- WPF (or Silverlight) Client

My "Problem":

I do not want to repeat the Validation Code in webserver and Client, but the Problem is, that "ModelBase" does not work as DataService data Transfer objects.
(The additional properties create all Kinds of Problems)

So - how would you usually tackle that Problem?

There are some ideas which come to mind:

- do not validate on server again (authenticated users are trustworthy?!)
- do not use WCF-DataService at all, but create custom WCF-Services (which maybe under the hood use the EntityFrameworks  db-context)

Both "Solutions" do not Sound very good...

Regards
Johannes Colmsee

Answer (score 0):

First note: **always validate on the server, never trust the client, never.**

The solution is to create a shared project with your shared code. There you can share the validation on both the server and client (with the same code-base).

Comment: And the shared Code would be? my model-classes? or "validator-classes" which work on an Interface? (ICustomer instead of concrete Customer type?)

Comment: Can be anything. Some people prefer to keep validation inside the model, some prefer to keep it outside. If you want  to keep it inside, share the models (with validation). Otherwise you can easily let both implement a shared interface and use custom validators (that create a ValidationContext).